# Mysterious SIGABRT in destructor if certain member variables are initialized in the constructor

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have the following Qt class:

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
private:
    void initializeGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
    void paintGL();

    double posX;
    double posY;
    double posZ;
};
```

When I put this in the constructor, my program produces a `SIGABRT` during `GLWidget::~GLWidget`:

```
this->posX = 0.0;
this->posY = 0.0;
this->posZ = 1.0;
```

These member variables aren't used anywhere else in the class. If I don't initialize the member variables, the program doesn't fail. How can this lead to a `SIGABRT`?

**Stack trace**

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: With questions like this, you should show more code, the error can't possibly be reproduced in your example.  The real error could be anywhere in your code.  The fact that adding these specific lines makes the program crash does not imply that the bug in the code is related to these lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the core file to see where it died?

That said, the most likely scenario is division by zero and/or assertion that X and Y are not zero.

EDIT: Also it seems likely that when you don't initialize the values the program is behaving wrong but it just *appears* to work correctly/better.

EDIT2 in response to comment: You can configure unix/linux systems (with `coreadm`) to leave a "core" file behind when you program crashes or aborts. It contains information about the call stack, registers, memory, etc. It does appear that you found it (or something similar). The line that says

> free(): invalid next size (fast):
>   0x00000000006e3110 ***

actually makes me change my mind. It looks like your heap is corrupted, and the deletion is causing that to become visible. One possibility is that you deleted the object twice. If you're on Linux, valgrind will probably be your best way to figure out what happened.

Comment: +1, only because you'll be a God when it turns out to be correct. :)

Comment: Valgrind information: http://pastebin.com/4mGhSz4v The error seems to be related to my graphics driver...

Comment: Valgrind information with a non-proprietary driver for my graphic card: http://pastebin.com/rpnvWtgg I get a `SIGSEGV` at startup when I use this driver.

Comment: Turns out that after cleaning, qmaking and rebuilding everything is working smoothly again. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Adding these variables moved code around. There's a bug somewhere that didn't cause a visible problem until the rearrangement occurred. I would run it in a debugger or add logging to it to determine where the problem is. Use the "Divide and conquer" method to minimize the time finding the bug.